# How to configure postman with magento 1.9 complete beginner

Tags: magento-1.9, api, extensions, oauth, postman

I don't know how to configure my Magento 1.9 with the postman.

I don't know how to check my API for postman (or any else).

I need to complete my work within 1 day but I don't know anything about these please help me step by step.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187529/49821
Check this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick Magento 1.x official guide for API Testing: You can use mozilla firefox plugin.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/testing_rest_resources.html